# Calculate time interval to 0.00 of the next day according to GMT in swift or objective-c?

Tags: swift, date, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I tried something like this:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
var dayFutureComponents = DateComponents()
dayFutureComponents.day = 1 // aka 1 day
var d = calendar.date(byAdding: dayFutureComponents, to: Date())
...//setting of d.hour, d.minute, d.second to zero and finding the difference between 2 dates
```

The problem is for example my current GMT is `+3`. So the result differs from one I need to achieve by 3 hours. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `Calendar` for the UTC timezone. Second get the `startOfDay using the UTC calendar. Third add one day to that date. Then you can use`Date`method`timeIntervalSince(_ Date)` to calculate the amount of seconds between those two dates:

```
extension Calendar {
    static let iso8601UTC: Calendar = {
        var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
        return calendar
    }()
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var secondsUntilStartOfDayTomorrowAtUTC: TimeInterval {
        return startOfDayTomorrowAtUTC.timeIntervalSince(self)
    }
    var startOfDayTomorrowAtUTC: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startOfDayAtUTC)!
    }
    var startOfDayAtUTC: Date {
        return Calendar.iso8601UTC.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
}
```

---

Playground Testing:

```
TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: Date()) / 3600 // -2 hours
Date().startOfDayAtUTC          // "Jan 18, 2018 at 10:00 PM"
let finalDate = Date().startOfDayTomorrowAtUTC  // "Jan 19, 2018 at 10:00 PM"
print(finalDate)  // "2018-01-20 00:00:00 +0000\n"
let seconds = Date().secondsUntilStartOfDayTomorrowAtUTC  // 29282.42592203617
let minutes = seconds / 60   // 488.0404320339362
let hours = seconds / 3600   // 8.134007200565604
```

Comment: This will give startOfDay of tomorrow at local time. You still need to use the Calendar at UTC timezone

Comment: kkkk ninja edit. You forgot to change `Date()` to `self`

Comment: Your original comment was using `Calendar.current`. The solution is to set the Calendar timezone to UTC. Both approaches would work. I prefer to separate them to have more flexibility (I can get today or tomorrow)

Comment: I don't want to nitpick. I deleted my other comments.

Comment: @vadian no problem. Note that it is a bit more complex than it looks like if you consider that depending on the timezone and the current time you can be 1 day ahead or behind

Answer (score 0):

Missed out that when I for example set hour to 0 - it displayed according to GMT (in my case it is 3 hours of difference). And When I calculate the difference between 2 dates - both dates has the same "displacement" so final result should be the same